# Google Cloud Composer call an API on failure

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-composer, google-cloud-error-reporting

I have a DAG running on the Google Cloud Composer. This DAG is executing some operations on top of our BigQuery (we are using `airflow.contrib.operators.bigquery_operator.BigQueryOperator`) I'd like to call the [Error Reporting API](https://cloud.google.com/error-reporting/reference/rest) if there is a failure in the DAG, however, I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Could you elaborate more on what you want to achieve and if you have done something so far ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is using the `on_failure_callback` parameter in the DAG args. This is a very good starter-level article on how to use it: https://forum.astronomer.io/t/how-can-i-set-my-on-failure-and-on-success-callbacks-to-have-the-task-context/182